# lttng error when ros2 launch

Tags: ros2, windows

I'm testing a ros2 launch file

```
ros2 launch pcl_ros sample_concatenate_data.launch
```

but I had this error:

> lttng module version >=2.10.7 required, found None

It seems that `lttng` is a python package, I tried `pip install LTTng-tools` but it does not install.

How should I fix this problem? should I build it from source? **https://lttng.org/docs/v2.10/#doc-building-from-source**

I'm using ros2 rolling built from source on Window11.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
As you said, please install it from the source. BTW, in the future, I strongly recommend sharing more information about the problem, such as which package and command you executed, etc. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: @ravi thanks, my test command and package name is updated.